# Cannot read property 'row' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, visual-studio

```
//anything inside 'pagebeforecreate' will execute just before this page is rendered to the user's screen 

$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", function () {
    printheader(); //print the header first before the user sees his page
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    searchfriend();

    function searchfriend() {
    var url = serverURL() + "/getcategories.php";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (arr) {
            _getCategoryResult(arr);
        },
        error: function () {
            validationMsg();
        }
    });
}

function _getCategoryResult(arr) {

    var t; //declare variable t
    //loop for the number of results found by getcategories.php
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        //add a new row
        t.row.add([ //error
            "<a href='#' class='ui-btn' id='btn" + arr[i].categoryID + "'>Category</a>" //add a new [Category] button
        ]).draw(false);

        //We drew a [View] button. now bind it to some actions
        $("#btn" + arr[i].categoryID).bind("click", { id: arr[i].categoryID }, function (event) {
            var data = event.data;
            showcategory(data.id); //when the user clicks on the [View] button, execute showcategory()
        });

    }
    $("#categoryresult").show(); //show the results in the table searchresult
}
function showcategory(categoryID) {
    //alert(categoryID);
    window.location = "showuser.html?userid=" + userid;

}
});
```

There is an error on line 33 which stated:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'row' of undefined"

However, it seems that I have no idea where the error is coming from.

Is there anyway I can solve this problem?

Comment: Somewhere, you're accessing `undefined.row`, or more likely a *variable* that is undefined. Hence, property row of undefined. Does that help?

Comment: Where is your `PHP` code?

Comment: What object is t supposed to be? From your code, it's just an undefined variable, hence the error you are getting.

Comment: Post your remaining code too.. HTML + PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look like you are using a third-party jQuery plugin, [DataTables](https://datatables.net/).
Follow the usage of DataTables.

```js
    var t; //declare variable t
```

should be

```js
    var t = $("#categoryresult").DataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `t` is not an object with a property called `row`. 
Try with `var t = { row: [] }`

Edit: I apologize. I got confused add with push method.

So, you need an object with a method called `add` and assign that object to `t`

Comment: It will lead to error `add is not a function` as `add` is not an Array.prototype function...